# TikZ / pgfmath: pgfmathprintnumber if not a number

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

[image]

I need a function

```
1) x=-1 ---> ERROR 
2) x < 0.01 --> 1000*x 
3) x --> x else
```

The problem: The result should appear into `\pgfmathprintnumber` and that collapses in case `1)`, because the word 'ERROR' is not a number.

What could I do?

BTW: *I wrote a lot with pgfmath in the main document and would like to stick with it instead of using something completely different here.*

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\x{5} % works


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Test}{1}{%%
\pgfmathparse{#1==-1}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 \pgfmathparse{"ERROR"} \else% 
  \pgfmathparse{#1<0.01}% 
   \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*1000}%
    \else \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \fi%
\fi}%%

123: \pgfmathparse{Test(123)}
 \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult} 
~pgfmathprintnumber works \\

0.0001: \pgfmathparse{Test(0.0001)} 
\pgfmathresult ~works but strange result  \\
\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult} 
~ better rounded with pgfmathprintnumber \\

-1: \pgfmathparse{Test(-1)} 
\pgfmathresult ~ works \\
%\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult} 
pgfmathprintnumber works not!
\end{document}
```

Comment: \pgdmathparse is limited to the dynamic range of TeX length registers (10000: 0.0001 IIRC).  \pgfmathparseFPU is much more accurate.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It's a common misconception that FPU is more accurate, which is not true. It has a larger range, but the same limitations in terms of accuracy as the normal one.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It doesn't. It stores mantissa and exponent separately. The format is `<flags>Y<mantissa>e<exponent>`.

Comment: After further research I discovered that `\pgfmathparseFPU` is not a standard command.  More to the point, it will not work without `\usepgflibrary{fpu}`, at which point `\pgfmathparse` also becomes more accurate.

Comment: It is a pity that pgfmath does not convert the FPU register to hexadecimal.  The first rule in applied math is "Never convert numbers to text while computing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\pgfmathprintnumber` internally calls `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber` which is part of the `fpu` library. The float parsing uses an error handler in case of invalid numbers which you can redefine.

The error handler is called `/pgf/fpu/handlers/invalid number` and has two arguments, the original input and the 'unreadable part'. Because there are two arguments the key `code 2 args` should be used to expose both `#1` and `#2`. Now you can print for example the original input as part of the error handling:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/handlers/invalid number/.code 2 args={#1}}
```

However, this is not yet sufficient. According to the PGF manual the error handler is intended to *correct* the invalid input, after which the control is handed back to `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber` (and subsequently to `\pgfmathprintnumber`). This means that you can either use the various math functions within the handler to assign a new value to `\pgfmathresult`, or do nothing, then `\pgfmathresult` will be `NaN` as resulting from the original call to `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber`. The value of `\pgfmathresult` is then passed down to `\pgfmathprintnumber` and will be displayed.

Therefore, the definition above results in the output `ERROR NaN`, with `ERROR` printed through `#1` in the error handler and `NaN` printed through further processing in `\pgfmathprintnumber`.

To get *only* the original input and *not* `NaN` in the output, some more modifications can be used. The idea is to modify the general code in `pgfmath` that prints the string `NaN` and turn this into a string that is conditional on a toggle. The error handler can turn the toggle to false, and the printing code can print the string if the toggle is true, and if it is false nothing is printed but the toggle is turned back to true to make sure `NaN` is printed when called from somewhere else.

Toggles and code patching functionality are provided by the `etoolbox` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{printnan}
\toggletrue{printnan}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl}% patch the pgf command for printing NaN
{\hbox{NaN}}% find the following code
% replace by:
{\iftoggle{printnan}{\hbox{NaN}}% print normally if toggle is true
{\global\toggletrue{printnan}}}% print nothing and set toggle to true if it is false
{}{}
\makeatother
\makeatother
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/handlers/invalid number/.code 2 args={#1\global\togglefalse{printnan}}}
\begin{document}
\def\x{5} % works

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Test}{1}{%%
\pgfmathparse{#1==-1}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 \pgfmathparse{"ERROR"} \else% 
  \pgfmathparse{#1<0.01}% 
   \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*1000}%
    \else \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \fi%
\fi}%%

-1: \pgfmathparse{Test(-1)} 
\pgfmathresult ~ works \\
\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}
pgfmathprintnumber prints the input unchanged\\

123: \pgfmathparse{Test(123)}
 \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult} 
~pgfmathprintnumber works \\

0.0001: \pgfmathparse{Test(0.0001)} 
\pgfmathresult ~works but strange result  \\
\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult} 
~ better rounded with pgfmathprintnumber \\

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]